# Assertion of Particular Exception which contains a field

Tags: java, assertj

Currently I have a test which tries to check a particular exception which looks like this:

```
assertThatExceptionOfType(DataIntegrityViolationException.class).isThrownBy(
        () -> xrepo.save(abc))
    .withCauseExactlyInstanceOf(ConstraintViolationException.class);
```

The exception `ConstraintViolationException` has a field `constraintName` available via getter `getConstraintName()` but I haven't found a way to check that via assertj.

I could imagine something like the following:

```
assertThatExceptionOfType(DataIntegrityViolationException.class).isThrownBy(
        () -> xrepo.save(abc))
    .withCauseExactlyInstanceOf(ConstraintViolationException.class)
    .with("getConstraintName").isEqualTo("XXXX");
```

or is there a different way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be:

```
.extracting(x -> ((ConstraintViolationException)x).getConstraintName())
.isEqualTo("XXXX");
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: I was expecting something like `.map(e -> e.getField())` so I didn't find this method, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`withCauseExactlyInstanceOf` does not change the object under test, but with [`havingCause()`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/ThrowableAssertAlternative.html#havingCause()) further assertions can be performed on the cause.

Combined with [`asInstanceOf()`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/Assert.html#asInstanceOf(org.assertj.core.api.InstanceOfAssertFactory)) and [`returns()`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractObjectAssert.html#returns(T,java.util.function.Function)), a type-safe check would be:

```
assertThatExceptionOfType(DataIntegrityViolationException.class).isThrownBy(
        () -> xrepo.save(abc))
    .havingCause()
    .asInstanceOf(type(ConstraintViolationException.class))
    .returns("XXXX", from(ConstraintViolationException::getConstraintName));
```

Or without type safety, using [`isInstanceOf`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/Assert.html#isInstanceOf(java.lang.Class)) and [`hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractObjectAssert.html#hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object)):

```
assertThatExceptionOfType(DataIntegrityViolationException.class).isThrownBy(
        () -> xrepo.save(abc))
    .havingCause()
    .isInstanceOf(ConstraintViolationException.class)
    .hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("getConstraintName", "XXX")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of @Eugene brought me to the direction:

```
assertThatExceptionOfType(DataIntegrityViolationException.class).isThrownBy(
        () -> xyrepository.save(xxx))
    .withCauseExactlyInstanceOf(ConstraintViolationException.class)
    .extracting(s -> ((ConstraintViolationException) (s.getCause())).getConstraintName())
    .isEqualTo("XXXX");
```

The solution of @StefanoCordio looks also fine...

Comment: Thanks for your help...